# Erro 2002 do MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou recém colocando um site pra hospedagem e já configurei as conexões do mysqli, mas ta dando esse erro aqui ao tentar executar o site:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Alguém sabe o que fazer pra arrumar isso?